# How to have an html hyperlink check multiple different web addresses?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am trying to create an html table full of gene sets. If the user clicks on a gene set, I want them to be sent to a new page with information about the gene set. Each gene set name is formatted as a series of strings joined by underscores, and only one of these strings is the identifier (the position varies). Here are some examples:

SPP382_blah --> "SPP382"

Blahblah_SPP382_complex_(human)  --> "SPP382"

The website https://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/Harmonizome/gene/ allows me to look up the gene sets, by placing the identifier after the last /. However, some gene sets are not in the database. For those, I want to open a google search of them.

I tried to generate the urls in the same Python code I used to create the table as follows, but it was too slow to generate all of the urls at once. I want to just generate the urls as the users click on the gene sets.

```py
import requests
def get_link(gene):
    geneTerms=gene.split("_")
    for ele in geneTerms:
        url = "https://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/Harmonizome/gene/"+str(ele).lower()
        request = requests.get(url)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            return url
    #return google search
    return "https://www.google.com/search?ei=AfpaXYasN8HW5gK0k5SYDA&q="+gene+"&oq="+gene+"&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39j0i131j0i20i263j0l4j0i20i263j0l2.31214.32485..32618...0.2..0.100.648.9j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i10.Eazm56dec2M&ved=0ahUKEwjGsL6K14_kAhVBq1kKHbQJBcMQ4dUDCAo&uact=5"
```

This runs very slowly for large tables. I think that the solution would involve a javascript function in my html file, but I am unsure of how to do this.

Comment: I do not think their website would like you hitting it like that too....

Comment: Yeah, that's another issue. If it only runs the script when the user clicks on a gene though, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Problem is JavaScript is same origin so it can not call the other domain so you would have to proxy the calls on the server.

Comment: I'm new to javascript and html, are you saying that the javascript function can only access pages on the website/app itself? And if so, how do I work around this?

Comment: Same Origin Policy

Comment: huh ok. Is there any good workaround for this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198249/discussion-between-inko-bovenzi-and-epascarello).